# OutputCache of .NET MVC5 App in Azure Falls Out of Cache Quickly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, caching

**My Goal**: *Cache basically all the pages all the time so that users rarely ever have to hit my CMS for content.*

I have a c#/.Net MVC 5 Web App deployed in Azure. I also have all the `OutputCache`'s on my controllers set for 1 week [604800s] (content rarely changes). I assume, maybe naively, that the cached outputs are stored in memory in Azure. However, when I start my app and crawl the website, I'd expect the Azure memory to fill up with cached content, but in practice, there *might* be a bump in memory utilization. It goes back to its "resting state" of like 60% utilization after about 5 mins, though. I've also tried using `MemoryCache`, but it has a similar result - a bump in memory usage, and it goes down to normal shortly after.

In any case, the result is that the pages act like they weren't cached. For example, if I crawl 1 page and visit it - it loads in about 1 second (it's cached). If i crawl 2000 pages and visit a random one, it loads in 3-4 seconds (it's not cached). I've tested this by putting a datetime in the view itself.

So... the bottom line is: cached = fast, not cached = average. I want it to be fast!

I've looked at Redis Cache, which could be a way to do this, and seems easy enough... but my gut says this should be basic functionality (since it's built into the framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web App did support in-memory OutputCache. We can easily confirm it using following code. The output datetime will not be changed after you refresh the TestCache page.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
public ActionResult TestCache()
{
    return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

But there are some problems when using in-memory cache in Azure Web App.

First problem with this is that it limits you to the memory that is available on your web app instance and this may create an out of memory issue when you cache a large amount of page output data. Your web app will be restarted if your memory is full. **If the web app is restart, all the cached content will be lost.** Another issue is that your application runs on multiple load balanced instances. The next request might go to another instance, which creates a new copy of ASP.NET Output Cache data in this instance, as well. These redundant copies of page outputs in each Web Role instance consume a lot of extra memory.

To avoid the upper problems, I suggest you use Redis Cache to store the cached content. For how to use Redis Cache, link below is for your reference.

[ASP.NET Output Cache Provider for Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-output-cache-provider)

Comment: Thanks! We figured out the multiple instance thing yesterday. That was a big issue with getting reproducible results. After reducing the number of instances, I also saw some web apps get reset after hitting 90% memory - I was hitting it hard with a load test.